# How to connect a bluefruit LE to a custom app from android studio?

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit

I am doing a little hovercraft for my school project and I want to control it with my phone. My option is a bluetooth connection because I have an adafruit bluefruit LE and an android phone. So I'm trying to make a custom app with android studio and simply sending the info to turn on or off the LED to verify if the connection is make. I searched all the information I needed and began my app, but when I am trying to click on the bluefruit to connect it to the phone, my application does nothing and when i retry, the app simply shut down. All the sources I take was about a HC-05 bluetooth module to connect to a arduino, so is that the problem? Like is there a specific line to change? Every info can help me because now I'm very clueless.

Thanks
Nico

Comment: The HC-05 bluetooth module is a Bluetooth Classic module. Bluefruit LE uses Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). These two are not compatible. You need to use BLE to connect to a BLE device. If you are already done working on the hovercraft you can use a generic BLE scanner app to connect to it and test the connection. One of the many options is 'nRF Connect'. If this is working you can start programming your own app. You can start with some basic informations about BLE (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le) and how to use it